# find and add inner level child node if entry is missing using groovy

Tags: groovy, xmlnode

Using groovy, I am trying to read the tomcat server.xml and insert a new node Resource   tag if node `<Resource name="jdbc/testDS" auth="Container" ..... >` is missing.

Server.xml has hierarchy as 
Server -> GlobalNamingResources -> Resource

Tried in 2 ways:-
1) Reading the server.xml

```
  groovy.util.XmlParser parser = new groovy.util.XmlParser();
  println "tomcat.directory.path for server.xml >> " + "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml"

  def root = parser.parse( "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml" )
  datasourceToAdd = parser.parseText("<Resource name=\"jdbc/testDS\" auth=\"Container\" type=\"javax.sql.DataSource\" driverClassName=\"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver\" url=\"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORA\" username=\"ORA_TEST\" password=\"*****\" factory=\"org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory\" defaultAutoCommit=\"false\" maxActive=\"10\" maxIdle=\"5\" maxWait=\"30000\" whenExhaustedAction=\"1\" driver=\"oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver\"/>");

  def nodeName = root.'**'.findAll { it.name()== 'jdbc/testDS' };
  println "nodeName >>>>>>> " + nodeName;
  if(!root.'**'.findAll { it.name()== 'jdbc/testDS' })  
  {
    root.find { it.name() == 'GlobalNamingResources' }.children().add( 0, fragmentToAdd )

    String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
    println outxml
  }
```

Problem here is writing data back to server.xml is not possible and condition is also incorrect. If condition is made correct, then writing the xml back to file needs to be done, did not find how to do this.

2) Reading the server.xml line by line and start writing to file and then insert the tag if entry is not found. Here also putting condition seems problematic.

```
  String cr = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
  File webXML = new File(  "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server2.xml"  )

  try
  {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream( "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml" );
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream( fstream );
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( dataInputStream ) );
    String strLine;

    //Read File Line By Line
    while ( ( strLine = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null )
    {
    println ">>>>>" + strLine;
    if(!strLine.contains("jdbc/testDS"))
    {
      webXML.append( strLine + cr );
    }
  }
  dataInputStream.close();
  AntBuilder ant = new AntBuilder()
  ant.move(file:  "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server2.xml" , tofile:  "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml" );
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {//Catch exception if any
    println( "Error: " + e.getMessage() );
  }
```

The two approach I tried won't give the desired result. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the `findAll` be:

```
root.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Resource' && it.@name == 'jdbc/testDS' }
```

So to make your first snippet a bit more 'groovy' you end up with:

```
new XmlParser().with { parser ->
  def root = parser.parse( 'C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/conf/server.xml' )
  String frag = '''<Resource name="jdbc/testDS"
                  |          auth="Container"
                  |          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  |          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                  |          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORA"
                  |          username="ORA_TEST"
                  |          password="*****"
                  |          factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
                  |          defaultAutoCommit="false"
                  |          maxActive="10"
                  |          maxIdle="5"
                  |          maxWait="30000"
                  |          whenExhaustedAction="1"
                  |          driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>'''.stripMargin()
  def fragment = parser.parseText( frag );

  if( !root.'**'.Resource.@name.find { it == 'jdbc/testDS' } ) {
    root.find { it.name() == 'GlobalNamingResources' }.children() << fragment
    String outxml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( root )
    println outxml
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this does work. But how can I write the new entry back in server.xml, above code is used for displaying the inserted entry. Should the approach be replace content of server.xml with content of outxml variable. Or to insert one line entry in server.xml.